# Laravel 5 Redis Connection error Exception when host is down or unreachable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, redis

I am using laravel version `5.5.*` with Redis for Caching. Everything is working perfectly. My controller codes are look like -

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller {

    public function showProfile($id) {

        if(!$user = Redis::get('user:profile:'.$id)){
          $user = SomeModelClass::user($id);
        }

        return view('user.profile', ['user' => $user]);
    }

}
```

My `config/database.php` file configuration is like -

```php
return [

    /*Other config*/

    'redis' => [

        'client' => 'predis',

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 1,
        ],
        'session' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 1,
        ],

    ],

];
```

**But when Redis server is down/unreachable, then below exception occurred.**

```php
Predis\Connection\ConnectionException (111)
Connection refused [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]
```

I want to run this method without any exception when Redis host is down/unreachable. Is there any option to do that? Help is appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller {

 public function showProfile($id) {

    if(!$user = $this->getUserFromCache($id))){
      $user = SomeModelClass::user($id);
    }

     return view('user.profile', ['user' => $user]);
  }
  private function getUserFromCache($id) {
     try{
         return Redis::get('user:profile:'.$id);  
     }catch(\Exception){
         // Log the error
         return null;
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But before executing this method getting Exception.

Comment: Make sure you dont make any connection to redis in other parts of the code such as service providers or middlewares

Comment: Redis is bootstrapped in service provider (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Redis/RedisServiceProvider.php) -- also this approach requires every request to be wrapped with boilerplate code. @SumonSarker you may check circuit breaker pattern for this.